# Get the value of a list that produces the maximum value of a calculation

Tags: python-3.x, list, max

I apologize if this is a duplicate, I tried my best to find an existing question but was unsuccessful.

Recently, I've run into a couple of problems where I've needed to find the element in a list that produces the max/min value when a calculation is performed. For example, a list of real numbers where you want to find out which element produces the highest value when squared. The actual value of the squared number is unimportant, I just need the element(s) from the list that produces it.

I know I can solve the problem by finding the max, then making a pass through the list to find out which values' square matches the max I found:

```
l = [-0.25, 21.4, -7, 0.99, -21.4]
max_squared = max(i**2 for i in l)
result = [i for i in l if i**2 == max_squared]
```

but I feel like there should be a better way to do it. Is there a more concise/one-step solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This will return you just the element which gives the max when squared.

```
result = max(l, key = lambda k: k**2)
```

Comment: but will only provide one of the two values

Comment: Agree. But since it's squared, obviously we regard the abs value. Do we reeealy need to save both in output?

Answer (score 0):

It does not get much better if you need the value in a list f.e. to see how often it occures. You can remeber the source element as well if you do not need that:

```
l = [-0.25, 21.4, -7, 0.99, -21.4]
max_squared = max( (i**2, i) for i in l)  # remeber a tuple, with the result coming first

print(max_squared[1])                # print the source number (2nd element of the tuple)
```

Output:

```
21.4
```

Your calculation does only return the first occurence of abs(24.1) because max only returns one value, not two - if you need both, you still need to do:

```
print( [k for k in l if abs(k) == max_squared[1]])
```

to get

```
[21.4,-21.4]
```